# I'm sending a value when clicking on checkbox in a html table it has to display selected value in text area. But uncheck is not working

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

Html :

```
<table id="customGroupupdatepersonTable" class="table table-bordered"">
  <thead>
    <tr class=" info">
      <th>check box</th>
      <th>Person Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="person_table">
      <% @all_person_names.each do |name| %>
      <tr id="tr_prsn_<%=name['id'] %>">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox_custom_B[]" onchange="clickedUpdateParamBox('<%=name['person_name']%>')">
        </td>
        <td style="word-break:break-all;">
          <%= name['person_name']%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function clickedUpdateParamBox(source) {
    var values = "," + source;
    if (!values.includes('{i}')) {
        document.getElementById("person_object_update").value =
            values.join("\n");
    } else if (values.includes('{i}')) {
        document.getElementById("person_object_i_value").value = values;
        var x = document.getElementById("update_person_i_value");
    }
}
```

**description:**

- when I click on checkbox it is adding that value into appropriate checkbox but if it has `{i}` in that value is displaying in a text area and if it is not having `{i}` it is showing in another checkbox. I am not able to apply to unselect code to this checkbox function.
- Help me to how to apply to uncheck code for this checkbox function now when I click for uncheck also it is adding that value into the text area.

Comment: Where's the text area? BTW you should replace the PHP with the HTML it ends up to be.

Comment: <textarea class="form-control" id="rdkv_object_update" style="overflow: scroll; height: 200px;"></textarea>

Comment: Edit the textarea in the appropriate place in your code. HTML is layout, layout is position, one without the other is a vague guessing game.